# How to fix the invalid syntax

Tags: python

In the section titled #Title type and size, I want to print out the pricing of each tile, but I cannot divide the numbers. How would I get around this? Thanks

```
print("Welcome to Terry Cotta's Tiling Company!")

#Dimenstion of area to be tiled
areaLength = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))
if areaLength <= 0:
    print('Area cannot be lower than 0')
    areaLength = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))
areaWidth = int(input('Input width of area to be tiled: '))
if areaWidth <= 0:
    print('Area cannot be lower than 0')
    areaWidth = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))
areaArea = areaLength*areaWidth

#Tile type and size
tiles = {'ceramic': '3', 'granite': '5', 'marble': '10'}

for x in tiles:
    print(x.title() + " -  Small: $" + int(tiles[x])/2 + "  Medium: $" + tiles[x] + "  Large: $" + int(tiles[x])*(2)

tileType = input("What type of tile would you like? Ceramic, granite or marble?: ")
tileType = tileType.lower()
while tileSuitable != 'yes':
    if tileType not in tiles:
        print('We do not provide that type of tile. Please enter again.')
        tileType = input("What type of tile would you like? Ceramic, granite or marble?: ")
if tileType in tiles:
    tileSize = input('What size tile would you like? Small, medium or large: ') 

#        else:
#            print(tileType.title() + ' costs $' + tiles[tileType])
#            confirmTileType = input('Is this your desired material? ')
#            confirmTileType = confirmTileType.lower()
#            if confirmTileType == 'no':
#                tileType = input("What type of tile would you like? Ceramic, granite or marble. Type 'cost' for cost of materials: ")
```

Comment: Copy&paste your error here.

Comment: It just says 'invalid syntax'

Comment: just try to comment some codes, you may find the right place for error. It's not good to simply paste all your codes here and ask other people to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you did not close the `print function`

**is:**

```
print(x.title() + " -  Small: $" + int(tiles[x])/2 + "  Medium: $" + tiles[x] + "  Large: $" + int(tiles[x])*(2)
```

**Should be:**

```
print(x.title() + " -  Small: $" + int(tiles[x])/2 + "  Medium: $" + tiles[x] + "  Large: $" + int(tiles[x])*(2))
```

**Small changes to your code:**

```
print("Welcome to Terry Cotta's Tiling Company!")
areaLength = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))


#You could loop until you get correct value


while areaLength <= 0:
    print('Area cannot be lower than 0')
    areaLength = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))
areaWidth = int(input('Input width of area to be tiled: '))

#Same here loop until you get the correct value 


while areaWidth <= 0:
    print('Area cannot be lower than 0')
    areaWidth = int(input('Input length of area to be tiled in metres: '))
areaArea = areaLength*areaWidth

tiles = {'ceramic': '3', 'granite': '5', 'marble': '10'}

for x in tiles:
    print(x.title() + " -  Small: $" + str(int(tiles[x])/2) + "  Medium: $" + tiles[x] + "  Large: $" + str(int(tiles[x])*(2)))

tileType = input("What type of tile would you like? Ceramic, granite or marble?: ")
tileType = tileType.lower()


#You had undeclared variable here so changed it


#And I really don't know what you were trying to do here 


while tileType != 'yes':
    if tileType not in tiles:
        print('We do not provide that type of tile. Please enter again.')
    tileType = input("What type of tile would you like? Ceramic, granite or marble?: ")
if tileType in tiles:
    tileSize = input('What size tile would you like? Small, medium or large: ')
```

Comment: Great, but now how would I get it to print all the prices out? I've tried converting to integers and stuff like that but it hasn't worked

Comment: @dbab see edit changed to your understanding

Comment: @VigneshKalai Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yep, marked as correct :)